# Unable to use Redmine REST API over https using node.js or postman at least

Tags: node.js, api, ssl, redmine

Using C# , we can do the following :

```
RedmineManager rm = new RedmineManager("https://<your-address>", <api-key>, "random-password");
IList<Issue> issues = rm.GetObjectList<Issue>(new NameValueCollection() { { "project_id", <project-id> } });
```

What about node.js ? known that I used also POSTMAN to query some REdmine REST endpoints , it popups the keychain screen to select the certificate, I select it however, the request is failed.

The response in POSTMAN is  :

Unauthorized

> This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the
>   document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g.,
>   bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the
>   credentials required

I run the same request with another redmine without SSL and it works .

My SSL certificate has extension p12 and i installed by my hand to make browser trust the domain name.

If is it a defect on REST provider ( Redmine ) let me know please .